# deque as an attribute in class in python

Tags: python, class

```
from collections import deque
class testClass:
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = deque()
    self.c = deque()
    self.a.append(1)
    self.c.append(2)

  def testFunc1(self):
    self.b = self.a
    self.a = self.c
    self.c = self.b
    print(self.b.pop())

  def testFunc2(self):
    self.b = self.a
    self.a = self.a.append(10)
    print(self.b.pop())

TestInstance = testClass()
TestInstance.testFunc1() #answer will be 1
TestInstance.testFunc2() #answer will be 10
```

I just dont understand why the two answers are different. Both functions first assign `self.a` to `self.b`. From the results, we can see that if we look at `testFunc2`, `self.b` **will change** if `self.a` changes. However, if we look at `testFunc1`, `self.b` **will not change** if `self.a` changes. Why this happened? Could anyone explain to me?

Comment: `self.b` *would* change if the deque originally pointed to by `self.a` (now referenced by `self.c`) changed. You should probably read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html to understand what all these assignments actually mean.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i just found another website which could visualize python codes. I find it extremely helpful to understand this type of question like mine.

Comment: forgot to add the link. The website mentioned above is http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to know which `deque` each attribute refers to after each assignment.

After `__init__` runs, you have two deques; let's say that `self.a` refers to `d1` and `self.c` refers to `d2`. Then `d1` contains the number 1 and `d2` contains the number 2.

When `testFunc1` is called, `self.b` is made to refer to `d1`. Then `self.a` is changed to refer to `d2`, and then `self.c` is made to refer to `d1`. The last line removes the value from `d1` and prints it, outputting 1.

When `testFunc2` runs, `self.a` still refers to `d2` and `self.b` and `self.c` both refer to `d1`. The first assignment makes `self.b` refer to `d2`. The next assignment adds 10 to `d2`, but then makes `self.a` refer to `None`, as that is what `deque.append` returns (*not* the updated `deque` itself). `self.b.pop()` immediately removes the 10 we just added to `d2`, and that value is printed.

Comment: thank you for your explanation. I think i get what you say, but still want to confirm with you about one thing. After the first assignment in `testFunc2`, both `self.a` and `self.b` refers to `d2`. `self.a.append(10)` will add 10 to `d2`, but it will return `None`. Hence,  the second assignment `self.a = self.a.append(10)` will make `self.a` point to a different object (which is `None`). At the same time, `self.b` still points to `d2` (which is just added by `10`). Is my understanding correct? Thanks again!

Comment: That’s it exactly.

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `self.b = self.a`.  By using = operator you think that this creates a new object; actually it doesn’t. It only creates a new variable that shares the reference of the original object. When you change `self.a` by appending another element, `self.b` changes as well, because they point to the same thing. Use copy() or deepcopy() depending on what you need. For this example, I think copy() is enough.

change `self.b = self.a` to `self.b = copy.copy(self.a)`, you will get what you expect. Please don't forget to `import copy`.

Read [copy in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/) for details.